# Email send from journey fails for some contacts - how to get error messages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a journey that is triggered by a salesforce data event, updates the object and sends an email afterwards. For most contacts the journey works fine but some contacts get injected into the journey, the object is updated via the "Choose Object"-Activity, but sending the mails fails. I already changed the email to one not using any AMPscript or other personalization so I can eliminate this reason for the failing send.

Checking the Contacts for the journey shows that the status of the email send is "Failed", but doesn't show any details. However the corresponding triggered send in email studio shows no failed sends. I also checked the chrome developer tools for any errors visible there, but didn't find any additional information.

Is there any way to get more information without creating a case for SFMC support? Or are there some common causes for such errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest checking a couple of things:

1. Open the Email and select **Send Preview**, then preview the email using your Event Source Data Extension to see if there are any errors.
2. Check that the [Channel Address Order](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/contacts_configuration/) is set correctly in Contact Builder — it could be that the email address for the Contact is not resolving correctly. Also, open your Journey Settings page (by clicking on the Cog icon) to check whether the email is derived from the Channel Address Order, or an Email field in your Event Source Data Extension.

My guess is that #2 is the most plausible explanation (failing to map email address for Contacts), given that there are no errors in the Triggered Send.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the meantime I changed to using the email fields from the data event and it seems to work. But as some journey entries worked before this could also be a coincidence. However, I just wondered if it's always better to use the email fields from the event rather than using channel address order for salesforce data event triggered journeys as new contacts possibly haven't been synced yet.

Comment: If you have a scenario where you are retrieving the email fields from a synchronised Data Extension and have not allowed a sufficient schedule before the event is fired (so the record does not exist), then it makes sense to use an email address field from your Event Source DE. Note that you can also choose both; open the Journey Settings page and set your Primary source as the Channel Address Order and secondary as Event Source — if the relationship does not exist in the Channel Address Order, then it will default to the Event Source DE email field.

Comment: If I have answered your question then please mark it as accepted for the benefit of others. Thanks!